# How to write out HTML from ajax call using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

This might seem a little simple, but i've tried many ways & non of them are working as expected.

i have values coming in from an ajax call, & i am displaying these to a `<table>`.
the data will not be seen at first (css - `display:none`) but `onclick` involves a function which displays a dialog of said data.

writing out the data in these ways does not work:

```
var text = "Example Data<br>";

var text = document.createTextNode("Example Data" + document.createElement('br'));

var text = document.createTextNode("Example Data");
    text += document.createElement('br');
```

The latter outputs `[object Text][object HTMLBRElement]`

How do i write this correctly??

Comment: Did you try `document.createTextNode("Example Data<br>")`?

Comment: Why not user jQuery selectors and .html() function()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't concatenate node objects (trying to do so with `+` will convert them to strings first).

Find the element you want to append the nodes you've created, and call `appendChild` on it repeatedly.

```
var text = document.createTextNode("Example Data");
someElement.appendChild(text);
someElement.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to append the line break 
 as an HTML element "createElement" as it is an HTML element.

```
var text = 'test';
var newtext = document.createTextNode(text),
    p1 = document.getElementById("p1");

p1.appendChild(newtext);
p1.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
p1.appendChild(document.createTextNode('newline displayed'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var p = document.createElement("p");
p.innerHTML = "Example Text<br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

1. Give the table an id
2. Append html response to the table by using `$('#tableid').html(responsedata);`

Comment: i used this method initially, however i found it conflicted with onclick functioning. this method will work, just not in my situation

Comment: conflict might be due to the dialog, but it is great that your issue has been solved!